# SimpleAds ad rotation delay

Tags: php, drupal

I have rotating ads set up in the SimpleAds module for Drupal 7.  I want to delay the rotation time.  I changed it from 5 seconds to 100 seconds, but it's still rotating at the same speed.  Has anyone dealt with this?  Is there a way to change this setting in the php?
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: In your screenshot there is a lot bigger number than 100 seconds?

Comment: How is the library jquery.cycle mapped with simple ads module?
How to configure ads_rotation_type and ads_rotation_delay?